# Quadrature subsampling result not as expected

Tags: downsampling, quadrature

Let's suppose I have an ADC running at 81.824MHz. I am quadrature subsampling a signal that is at 143.5MHz using a sampling rate of 81.824MHz/4 = 20.456MHz = Fs. I expect the signal to appear at baseband with a small offset of 143.5MHz-7*Fs = 308KHz. But it is showing up at 320KHz when I run the code below. Why is that?

```
% Sampling frequency 
fs = 20.456;

% ADC frequency
fadc = 4*fs;

% ADC period
T = 1/fadc;

% Some ADC samples
n = 0:T:100;

% Received frequency
f_l1 = 143.5;
s_l1 = cos(2*pi*f_l1*n);

% Replica frequency for mixing.
f_local = 7*fs;
s_local = cos(2*pi*f_local*n);

% Mixing
sif = s_l1 .* s_local;

% Find frequency content
siffft = (fft(sif));

% Plot results
nyquist = 1;
freq_steps = (1:length(siffft))/(length(siffft))*nyquist*fadc;
figure(3);
plot(freq_steps, abs(real(siffft))), 
grid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct; `sif` has a harmonic at 308 kHz. Given the way you have set up the problem, you can't get that exact value using the FFT because you don't have a frequency bin at that frequency. According to my calculations, the nearest bin is at 305 kHz, and I do see a peak at that frequency. Since there is no bin at the signal's frequency, the energy will leak: bins in the neighborhood of the peak will also get some of the energy of the 308 kHz signal.

Leakage is very hard to avoid. Assuming a fixed sampling frequency, you can calculate the number of samples you need to have a bin at exactly 308 kHz. However, it's very likely that you will then have a non-integer number of cycles of `sif`, so you will have leakage again. This effect can be reduced by using windowing.

There are many related questions in this website (for example, [this one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10120/why-does-spectral-leakage-arise-in-an-fft)). Search for 'fft bin leakage' to find many more.